# Can I check if my current route is in a given list of routes?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Is it possible to do this more generic?

```
  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
    if(this.$route.path === '/home'){do something with id 1}
    if(this.$route.path === '/'){do it not - its not in the array}
    if(this.$route.path === '/about'){do something with id 3}
   }
  }
```

I ask because I dont want to have a long snake of if else conditions for every route I need to check and to avoid such stuff with maybe 50 routes like this:

I need to check if the current route is in a given list of routes and if so return an id from the array and if not return another id for not found but having problems to get the method running.

```
myArray: [{id: '1', path: '/home'}, {id: '3', path: '/about'}]

if(myArray.includes(this.$route.path)
return this.id
else return 666
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the data you want to act on in a `meta` property of each route.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      meta: { id: 1 }
    },
    {
      path: '/bar,
      component: Bar,
      meta: { id: 2 }
    }
  ]
})
```

Then when you watch the `$route` you can perform a more generic action on `$route.meta.id`.